# Google services hangs on Opera

Tags: google-workspace, opera

I am able to login in to the company's Google services homepage (`https://www.google.com/a/example.com`). However, after login, I experience a redirect to `https://admin.google.com/UserHub` and the page hangs at *Loading...*

[image]

Searching for "Opera", "hang" and the URL "https://admin.google.com/UserHub" returns 0 results.

I've rebooted the machine twice, and the problem remains.

How can I determine the cause of the issue with Linux/Opera/Google?

---

I can't find a support phone number or email address for Google.

Does Google provide *real* support when they have real customers paying real money? Or is it more self help on the web?

---

Machine and browser information follows.

**Opera**: Version 12.16; Build 1860; Platform Linux; System x86_64, 3.13.0-37-generic

**Identification**: Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16

**Ubuntu**: 14.04.1, x64 (fully patched)

**Uname**: 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera isn't a supported browser. From [Supported browsers - Google Apps Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33864?hl=en)

> Google Apps supports the following browsers:
>
> - Chrome
> - Internet Explorer
> - Firefox
> - Safari

Comment: Not a surprise... Opera is basically a WebKit/Blink based browser Google can support, they just refuse to. The tricks Browser makers play in an attempt to increase their market share is disgusting.

Comment: @jww : Maybe at this time Google services will work on current version o Opera (I'm using a Chromebook at this moment, so I can't do tests now). From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_(web_browser):
On 28 May 2013, a beta release of Opera 15 was made available,[30] the first version based on the Chromium project.[31][32].